# How do I extract an element from an array in javascript and then make it an entirely new, single-element array?new

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers like

```
[1, 10, 100]
```

The question is: how can I extract numbers from this array and transform these numbers into new, single-element arrays like

```
[1], [10], [100]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I extract numbers from this array and transform these numbers
>   into new, single-element arrays like `[1]`, `[10]`, `[100]`

Simply use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the item wrapped in an array and finally return a new array **having every item as single item array.**

```
arr.map(s=>[s])
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log([1, 10, 100].map(s=>[s]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to map each item into a separate array. And if you know the count and want to keep them into separate variables, you can use [**array destructuring**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const singleItemArray = [1, 10, 100].map(item => [item]);

console.log(singleItemArray); // Array of single item arrays

const [first, second, third] = singleItemArray; // Destructuring the array of arrays into single arrays

console.log(`first: ${first}`);
console.log(`second: ${second}`);
console.log(`third: ${third}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) while mapping the arrays.

```js
var [a, b, c] = [1, 10, 100].map(v => [v]);

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple ES5 answer: 
`oldArray.map(function(item) { return [item]; });`;